# PayPal Express Checkout in Sandbox leaves transactions 'Pending'

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I've integrated PayPal Express Checkout using the method at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/integrate/#1-set-up-your-development-environment , with the JS SDK.

Everything works fine and I am able to create a button with the amount and the transaction succeeds. However, I don't see the money coming into the sandbox business account. I do see the transaction on the sandbox personal account, but it's pending on approval from seller, which I don't see there.

Not sure if this is sandbox behaviour or if I have something wrong.

The src script which I load is:

```
https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=${clientId}&currency='CAD'&disable-funding='credit,card,bancontact,blik,eps,giropay,ideal,mybank,p24,sepa,sofort,venmo'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely problem is that the receiving account's email address is not confirmed in sandbox.

To check, navigate to https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/businessprofile/settings/email , log in with the receiving sandbox account, and resend any necessary confirmation message

To open the confirmation message, log in with your live developer account at https://www.paypal.com/signin?intent=developer&returnUri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.paypal.com%2Fdeveloper%2Fnotifications%2F and follow the link there to do the confirmation

Comment: thanks so much! i would have never figured that out